# What is the meaning of reared its head?

Tags: idioms

I was reading a motivational article but I don't get it and I don't want to assume so I came here to ask :) if you can give me more examples.

(Note) any feedback would be greate.

## Article.

You have two choices... quit or move forward. Since quitting is not an option, you must push forward. Sure, the uncertainties of life can overwhelm you, but you are equipped for the task! It is important to stand in your reality. Whatever issue or obstacle that has currently ***reared its head*** in your life, you must stare it in the face, identify it, and make it your purpose to overcome it. Identifying the issues in your life removes fear of the unknown and forces you to focus on defeating the problem at hand.

Author:By Amy Oraefo at http://www.huffingtonpost.com/entry/when-your-back-is-against_b_5302153.html

Answer (score 1):

Taken from [World Wide Words](http://www.worldwidewords.org/qa/qa-rea2.htm): It refers to something that has made an unwelcome appearance or has become a troublesome subject that requires attention.

You'd use it in any situation where something unexpected and unpleasant has happened.

I've commonly heard it used in anticipation of something unpleasant happening like this: Don't go running or your heart problem might rear its head again.

The above example is quite graphic but it gets the point across.

Comment: A similar common phrase is "reared its *ugly* head" which is idiomatic and emphasizes the unpleasant part.